All commands need Ctrl-c in Linux terminal
Each time I type a command in Linux terminal, the cursor doesn't go to a newline and I have to Ctrl-c in order to get a newline.
I already tried the reset command but it doesn't work.
This happened since I typed cd (as a habit) while the terminal was still loading when I start it.

If you start a new terminal, does it have the same behaviour? Have you changed your fish config recently? What do your fish_prompt and fish_right_prompt functions do?

Does using Ctrl/J work any better? (For example, date and then Ctrl j insted of Enter). If so, try stty sane and follow that with Ctrl j

All good questions above. Be sure to update the body of your question with that information rather than replying in comments AND also include the output of echo $TERM ; stty -a . Use the {} tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to achieve correct code/data/output/errMsg formatting.

Fish resets terminal modes pretty thoroughly, so that's unlikely. The most likely explanation here is that the prompt just takes longer than you're willing to wait. Try setting a simpler prompt, like function fish_prompt; echo $PWD ">"; end.
